# Is this language context-free or not?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I have a problem to solve, the problem is:

> Is the language of strings
>
> $$L=\{0^x1^y:x\nmid y\}$$
>
> context free?

I suspect it isn't, I spent some time trying to make a grammar that could generate that language, but I couldn't and I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I think one can use [Parikh's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem) to show that this is not context-free, maybe that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a set of production rules that produce the strings, which seems to fail the Wikipedia definition of [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).

$S \rightarrow 1 S$

$1S \rightarrow S0$

$S0 \rightarrow \emptyset$

As far as the restriction you mentioned on the produced strings, I don't know how that factors in.  Hopefully this can help you.

Comment: -1, that there is a context-sensitive grammar says nothing about whether the language is context free